# How to Browse a particular folder

Tags: c#

I have a folderBrowserDialog control and i have a button named click
i did like this way

```
 private void click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you wish to accomplish is to automatically display a folder of your choice whenever the `FolderBrowserDialog` is shown, then you can use the following code:

```
private void click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FolderBrowserDialog f = new FolderBrowserDialog();

    f.Description = "Please browse to, and select a folder";
    f.RootFolder = @"C:\Name Of Folder You Want Displayed\";

    using(f)
    {
        if(f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Do something when the user clicks OK or Open.
        }
    }
}
```

Or, you could simply add a `FolderBrowserDialog` to your Form from the Visual Studio ToolBox and click on the Properties tab, and then click the down arrow to the right-hand side of the 'Root Folder' option and select one of the listed folders from the drop-down menu.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom build Folder Browser Dialog/Control for this. Try this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/FileBrowser.aspx